# Can I give parameters to AppConfig.ready() of django?

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I want to get request.user.id as I have to pass it to scheduler in AppConfig.ready() but it gave an error. How can I do it ?

My code is as follows:

```
class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self, request):
        print('Here starting scheduler')
        
        from . import msgScheduler
        user_id = request.user.id

        msgScheduler.start(self,request, user_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ready` function is not called by HttpRequest, so you cannot get any request or authenticated user...

You have to start your scheduler without a request/user or run the `start` function from a view

Comment: Okay I understand that.

But can you tell me something where I can simply start the scheduler without request but whenever an api (which is already created) runs, I add a job to the scheduler and delete the previous one, I don't know how to code that.

Comment: @GurleenKaur How can I tell you how start your scheduler, while I have no idea what it is and you didn't put the code for it?

Comment: I want to ask, how do I add the job from external view file to the scheduler ?

Comment: I repeat, how do you expect me to tell you how to run scheduler when I don't know what it is? It is a package? is this code you wrote? what are the input options? do you have documentation?